# Converting a vector in R into a lower/upper triangular matrix in specific order

Tags: r, matrix, vector, triangular

I have a vector where the order of the elements are important, for example:

`v<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

I would like to arrange my vector into a lower/upper triangular matrix with a specific order:

```
1 2 4 7
0 3 5 8
0 0 6 9
0 0 0 10
```

or

```
1 0 0 0
2 3 0 0
4 5 6 0
7 8 9 10
```

I think I can make it whith a for, but I don't know how, and blanks could be filled with NAs or 0's

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fill up the upper triangular matrix by doing

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
mat[upper.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)] <- v

mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    4    7
#[2,]    0    3    5    8
#[3,]    0    0    6    9
#[4,]    0    0    0   10
```

Lower triangle doesn't follow the same sequence as upper triangle so doing

```
mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)] <- v
```

doesn't give the expected outcome.

We can get the indices of lower triangle, `order` them according to row and then update the matrix

```
order_mat <- which(lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
mat[order_mat[order(order_mat[, 1]), ]]  <- v

mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    2    3    0    0
#[3,]    4    5    6    0
#[4,]    7    8    9   10
```

Or as @Gregor commented a much simpler way is to transpose the upper triangular result

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
mat[upper.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)] <- v #Upper triangle
t(mat)   #Lower triangle
```